# Finiteness of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n 2i(1-x_i)}{n-1-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}$ for $0<x_i<1$.

Tags: limits, summation

Alrighty, this one is a bit of a doozy I think.

Let's say I have this limit

$$f(x) > \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (2i (1 - x_i))}{n - 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i}$$

Where $0 < x_i < 1$ for all $i$, $x_i$ is unknowable otherwise.
My first thought is to distribute the top

$$f(x) > \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (2i - 2i \cdot x_i)}{n - 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i}$$

Break up the summation

$$f(x) > \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n 2i - \sum_{i=1}^n 2i \cdot x_i}{n - 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i}$$

Split the fraction and distribute the limit. (limit of sum = sum of limits)

$$f(x) > \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n 2i }{n - 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i} - \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {\sum_{i=1}^n 2i \cdot x_i}{n - 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i}$$

Do the sum in the first part

$$f(x) > \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ n(n+1) }{n - 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i} - \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {\sum_{i=1}^n 2i \cdot x_i}{n - 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i}$$

Then this is kinda where I get stuck. If in that first part, I divide by n on the top and bottom, I'll get something like

$$f(x) > \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ (n+1) }{1 - \frac{1}{n} - \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i }{n} } - \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {\sum_{i=1}^n 2i \cdot x_i}{n - 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i}$$

I know that because $x_i < 1$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i < n$, so I suspect, that first part is going to look something like

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ (n+1) }{1 - \frac{1}{n} - \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i }{n} } \to \frac{\infty+1}{1 - 0 - 0} \to \infty$$

I know that the second part is going to be smaller than the first because $x_i < 1$, so $\sum_{i=1}^n 2i \cdot x_i < \sum_{i=1}^n 2i$, but I don't know if that's going to help me at all here. I don't know if L'Hopital's rule would be of any help here, but maybe because $x_i$ is just a number, I get something like

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac { \frac{d}{dn} \sum_{i=1}^n 2i \cdot x_i}{\frac{d}{dn}n - 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i}$$

Then the denominator would become

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac { \frac{d}{dn} \sum_{i=1}^n 2i \cdot x_i}{1}$$

But I don't know if I can do any of this in the first place. I have the feeling that I've broken a whole lot of rules to get just this far.

Are there other or more sophisticated tools I could use to understand and solve this?

Ultimately, I'm trying to check whether or not $f(x)$ is divergent. I strongly suspect it is, but I can't seem to prove it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It is not clear what you’re trying to accomplish. What is the relevance of $f(x)$?

Comment: @FShrike Ultimately, I'm trying to check whether or not $f(x)$ is divergent. I strongly suspect it is, but I can't seem to prove it. Edited the main post for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define $y_i=1-x_i\in (0,1)$. The conditions that describe converge or divergence of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n 2iy_i}{-1+\sum_{i=1}^n y_i}=2\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n iy_i}{-1+\sum_{i=1}^n y_i}$ are a combination of inequalities on $\sum_{i=1}^\infty y_i$ and finiteness of $\sum_{i=1}^\infty iy_i$. I think any reasonable person would agree that conditions such as those are more or less primitive.

More precisely:

1. $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n iy_i}{-1+\sum_{i=1}^n y_i}=\infty$ if and only if $\sum_{i=1}^\infty y_i>1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty iy_i=\infty$;
2. $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n iy_i}{-1+\sum_{i=1}^n y_i}=-\infty$ if and only if either $\sum_{i=1}^\infty y_i<1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty iy_i=\infty$ or $\sum_{i=1}^\infty y_i=1$.

If $\sum_{i=1}^\infty iy_i=\infty$, then apply Stolz-Cesaro to the reciprocal $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-1+\sum_{i=1}^n y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n iy_i}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{y_n}{ny_n}=0$$ And therefore the original limit will be infinity with the appropriate sign: $+\infty$ if $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i-1$ is eventually positive (i.e. if and only if $\sum_{i=1}^\infty y_i>1$ ) and $-\infty$ if $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i-1$ is eventually negative (i.e. if and only if $\sum_{i=1}^\infty y_i\le 1$).
If $\sum_{i=1}^\infty y_i=1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty y_i<\infty$, then in the original limit we have an indeterminate form $\left[\frac{\alpha}{0^-}\right]$ with $\alpha>0$, which is in fact $-\infty$.

Finally, if $\sum_{i=1}^\infty iy_i<\infty$ and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty y_i\ne 1$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n iy_i}{-1+\sum_{i=1}^n y_i}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^\infty iy_i}{-1+\sum_{i=1}^\infty y_i}$.

Comment: Theres a lot of things in here that I don't understand exactly, but I think the information is all here that I need to answer my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the entirety of Stolz-Cesaro. I have just one more question right now. We're using 

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i}{-1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} iy_i}$$

Can this be generalized to 

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i}{-c + \sum_{i=1}^{n} iy_i}$$

Where c is some constant, or does it need to be $-1$?

Comment: @TinyTim You are not writing the right things, but for all $c>0$ you can say for $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n iy_i}{-c+\sum_{i=1}^n y_i}$ the same thing I said in the original, except that you have to substitute $1$ with $c$.

Comment: I wrote up another post in which I attempted to use the Stolz-Cesaro Theorem to solve this problem, but I'm worried I've missed a bit of the nuance you have. If you'd be willing, could you take a look at it? If not, could you refer me to some other sources for learning Stolz-Cesaro, I wish I had a better grasp on it but I'm not sure where to look to learn it better. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the nature of the $x_i$. Before writing this, I tried:

- $x_i=1-\frac{1}{2i}$
- $x_i=1-\frac{1}{(2i)^2}$
- $x_i=1-\frac{1}{(2i)^3}$

The first two has the limit as divergent. We need the $x_i$ to tend to $1$ fairly fast. The third makes the limit converge, and indeed converge to: $$-\frac{\pi^3}{24-3\zeta(3)}<0$$So you cannot even conclude $f$ is a positive function.

If you substitute $y_i=1-x_i$, you just need to consider: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2\sum_{i=1}^ni\cdot y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^ny_i-1}$$Where $0<y_i<1$. A *necessary* condition that this converges is that some subsequence $(y_{n_k})\to0$, or that some subsequence $(x_{n_k})\to1$. Otherwise, there is some $\delta>0$ that $1>y_i>\delta$ for all $i$ and I can bound: $$\frac{2\sum_{i=1}^n i\cdot y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n y_i-1}>\frac{\delta\cdot n(n+1)}{n-1}\to+\infty$$

Comment: This is very helpful, I'll be pondering this for the next bit. Thank you for the feedback!